# Overlay not in full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I've checked some answers for the overlay full height problem, but there's no proper answers.

How do you make an overlay to cover the whole page instead of part of it, which is annoying. And I'm doing height equals to 100%.

The overlay is made in jquery but obviously, the css can be done in a css file. But for the sake of simplicity...:

```
$('.overlay-test').click(function(e){
  $('#ovelay-box').load('overlay.html', function(response){
    $('#ovelay-box').css({
        "opacity": 0.5,
        "background": "#333",
        "height": $('body').height(),
        "position": "absolute",
        "width": "100%",
        "top": 0,
        "color": "#333",
        "font-size": "26px",
        "font-weight": "bold"
    });

    $('.overlay').addClass('col-12-box').css({
        "width": "770px",
        "left": "129px",
        "background": "#fff",
        "padding": "20px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "50px"
    });
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the jquery

```
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var docWidth = $(document).width();

$("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");

$(".overlay").css({
    "height":docHeight,
    "width":docWidth
});

$(".showOverlay").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".overlay").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
});
```

thc css

```
.overlay {
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

the html

```
<a href="#" class="showOverlay">show overlay</a>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: but when I use $(document).height(), there is a small gap between the overlay box and the bottom of the page. I don't want the gap...

Comment: are you setting the body or html height to 100%? if so take this off.

Comment: also have you hidden overflow? the small gep could be where the scrollbar would be.

Comment: Updated answer to include all css and html as well to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thanks for your answer... It works

Answer (score 4):

Another method for doing the overlay that can often overcome some of the pesky "gap" issues is to use this absolute positioning trick:

```
#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Which will essentially attach it to all sides of the view port regardless of size:

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6DKgb/2/

Also don't forget to remove the default padding that gets added to the body by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
body, html { height: 100% }
```

`body` does not fill all vertical screen space by default.  So your overlay is 100% of the height of it's parent, but that isn't the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Fix directly in magnific_popup.js updateSize function.  Add the following:

```
mfp.bgOverlay.css({
  height: _document.height(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this too

```
$(".overlay").css({
   position:fixed,
   top:0px,
   bottom:0px,
   width:100%
});
```